# Is there a way I can track a particular question in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Sometimes I come across questions that are interesting and I would like to track them for new answers/updates. Is there a way/setting to do this?

Comment: Hey @Krishna. According to the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq) this question would best be asked on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ since it is about the site, but not about programming.

Comment: This should be asked in meta.  But you can "favorite" a question by clicking the star icon on the left.

Answer (score 4):

This is going to Meta, but you could use the RSS feeds:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/QUESTIONID
```

Comment: An email notification would have been nice.

Comment: I wish there were a far easier way.  I'm not sure what to do with an RSS feed. Can I turn it into a convenient email alert that tells me when there has been new activity on a question?

Answer (score 3):

You can make them a 'favorite' by click on the star below the vote count.

Then you can revisit the question at a later time.