# How do question bookmarks work?

Tags: support, faq, bookmarks

- What does bookmarking a question mean?
- How do you bookmark a question?
- Do users get updates on their bookmarked questions?
- Are my bookmarks publicly visible?
- How do you see your own bookmarks?
- How do you see other users' bookmarks?
- How do you see which users have bookmarked a particular question?
- What impact does the bookmark system have on the voting system?
- Can I "un-bookmark" a question?
- Can I search within my bookmarks?

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/)

Comment: I wonder if I could increase that number by replacing the graphic in the answer with a screenshot of this question. (After putting in a freehand circle and arrow, of course.)

Comment: I love the irony that this question has been selected *as a favourite* by 152 users (= 70% of the number of upvotes)!

Comment: @Chappo keep in mind favoriting can be done with 1 rep, upvote requires 15 rep. So good chance many of those who favorited has below 15, so couldn't upvote.

Comment: Should we update this in light of [Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/)? Or should a new post be created to replace this one? It doesn't seem all that useful keeping around an FAQ for a now-removed feature, but I also see some merit in creating a new post from scratch precisely because Saves is a new feature altogether.

Answer (score 211, accepted):

A question is bookmarked by clicking the icon beneath the vote counter:

> [image: Bookmark]

A number beneath the icon shows the number of users who have bookmarked a specific question. Bookmarking a question basically says that a particular user feels like saving that question to be able to easily find it again later. It's completely separate from the voting system and has no impact on question scores or user reputation. However, having a question bookmarked by enough users does make you eligible to earn certain badges.

Bookmarking a question allows you to easily check back to see when updates are made to the post and reference it again in the future.

- Any question you bookmark will be listed in [your user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) under the tab "bookmarks". This lets you find it easily when the question may otherwise get lost.
- The bookmarks tab on your profile has a counter indicating how many of your bookmarked questions have received answers since you last viewed that tab. When you click on the tab, recently changed questions will be highlighted. "Changed" includes comments on or edits to the question and new or edited answers. This is a way to get updates on questions that you yourself didn't ask.

> [image: bookmark tab counter]

There is no limit to the number of bookmarks you pick. Furthermore, you can remove a bookmark at any time by just clicking on the same icon either on the question itself or in your user profile. There is no limit to the number of times you can add or remove a question from your bookmarks.

To search within your bookmarks, add the term `inbookmarks:mine` to your search query.

You can see the bookmarks of other users in their profile pages, and which users have bookmarked a specific question by using [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/299308/favorite-users-by-question) on the [Data Explorer site](https://data.stackexchange.com), for example [list of users who bookmarked this very question](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/299308/favorite-users-by-question?PostID=53585).

Comment: favourite (sic) == bookmarking

Comment: IMO this is a privacy issue. Sometimes, I may not want others to see what I have 'favorited'. So there should be another option that allows us to keep a list of private favorites.

Comment: Furthermore, it only favorites questions. What I really need is to jump directly to answers.

Comment: It seems that you can check for updates to your favorites by clicking on your favorites tab and sorting by activity.

Comment: @Jus12 I agree public favourites is a privacy issue. You may be interested in my answer here http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138723/189918

Comment: @Jus12, I suppose you *could* just bookmark the pages that you don't want anyone to see. I think it would be a privacy issue if bookmarks didn't exist, but rather, it is just an additional option for users. By that logic, posting questions/answers would also be a privacy issue.

Comment: I've been a user of SO for many years and only now realized fully what this feature (favoring) means. Maybe I'm alone about this but I think this feature should be renamed to something like "bookmark" or "follow" it would be much more apparent what it does. I kind of always thought that favorite meant a stronger kind of vote up.

Comment: @Ciro they won't. It might happen at some point in the future,  but even this is not sure.

Comment: @Jonny makes a very good point and i'm in the same boat (and the boat seems to have a leak!). I think i'll start using it, but hold my nose each time, because i wish to mark *bad* questions (or bad answers) that i have made suggestions/comments on, and i wish to come back to see if my advice has been followed. They're actually my *least* favorite Qs, but i *do* wish to track them.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Any good arguments against?

Comment: @Sean against what? Notifications? No arguments, personally I want them too, but knowing the system also aware it's not likely to happen. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, notifications. I suppose it could be prohibitively challenging depending on how notifications are set up in the design.

Comment: @Sean it might be simple to do technically, I suspect the lack of notifications is due to decision of the team, e.g. they think it would annoy more than be helpful by flooding the inbox.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I can see that. It would certainly overwhelm many of us who've mistaken it as a thumbs-up (like Johnny above). I've *hundreds* of such questions. If this concept is ever to be implemented, I suppose it *would* have to be a new data point.

Comment: Is there a limit on the number of favourite questions I can have?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Technically, they could add this feature only to stars given after the date of introduction of the feature and add a pop-up explaining the new feature. Regarding information overload: It's a natural part of Quora to follow questions and the notifications have never interfered with my own activities, so I'm not seeing that as a problem based on my experience.

Comment: @mcb I think you commented on the wrong post.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not. I'm responding to your or the dev team's claim that the notifications would flood the inbox, and Sean's claim that existing stars would pose a problem.

Comment: My Favorites tab says I have 0 questions even though I have one.. this doesn't work. :(

Comment: I found it, finally! I suspect the interface has changed. The "favorites" tab cannot be found under the "Profile" tab at the top. You need to switch to the "Activity" tab at the top first.

Comment: it will be better if we get notifications for changes made for our favorite questions.

Comment: Searching 'infavorites:mine' works for other sites, like on AI Stack Exchange. Initially, I checked and could only find favorites under the tab for this Meta website on my profile here, but then I tried that and it worked. There is not a Favorites tab on my profile for other sites like the AI one.

Comment: If you click the link "Network Profile" next to your username in the top right corner of the page, that will take you to your profile page with a favorites tab for all of the exchanges you participate in.

Comment: @user2277550 The answer states "There is no limit to the number of bookmarks you pick."

Comment: I just wanna mention, on stackoverflow at least, using inbookmarks:mine wasn't working as expected. Instead I had to append in:saves at the end of my search...

Comment: The icon has changed, please change the picture