# Where are my starred Questions?

Tags: support, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Stack Overflow has a feature that you can star whatever questions you like, but how can I find my starred questions and their answers? Where is it?

Comment: Make sure to sign up on Meta, you can post questions like this there. Check the bottom of the page for the link.

Comment: Just marked this question as a favourite.
Only after did I realize the catch 22 :)

Comment: This is a pressing issue. Someone needs to address this urgent question.

Comment: shameless plug but i made a extension to easily view starred questions on a sidebar whenever you browse stackoverflow: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackoverflow-starred-vie/cnamfgnggohmnbilcjdnjjahlgkndhmp?hl=en

Answer (score 75):

Look on [your profile page under Favorites](https://stackoverflow.com/users/339885?tab=favorites#tab-top).

Comment: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/339885?tab=favorites#tab-top)

Comment: I can confirm that the feature is done poorly. Within my profile that tab had the selection border on by default. This is what led me to search for an answer instead of clicking on it. Sorting by newest still shows random dates and the latest starred question is not listed...

Comment: Here are YOUR favorites (yes, you dear user, reading this now): https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=favorites

Comment: @BenRacicot You need to sort by `added` (`?tab=favorites&sort=added`) to see your latest starred questions.

Comment: @mwfearnley ty my captain. i just wondered, why i wasnt able to find this when accessing the site from my mobile phone.

Comment: literally i can't find the favorites under the profile tab

Comment: Would this be considered recursion if I starred this question?

Comment: looks like favorites have been renamed bookmarks

Comment: And now it's been renamed "saves".