# Where are favorites listed?

Tags: support, bookmarks

So I marked a question as favorite by clicking the star next to it, but now I can't find it - where do I go to get a list of my favorited questions? Or is the star just a rating thing, not a bookmark?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are my starred Questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54276/where-are-my-starred-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're listed on the "favorites" tab of your profile.

So here on meta they'd be at:

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/153712/benubird?tab=favorites

For your SO account they're at:

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/494643/benubird?tab=favorites

[image: Your Favorites]