# Where can I find my favourite questions in Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are my starred Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54276/where-are-my-starred-questions)

I have added (star /to Fav) some questions here to answer them later, but now I don't know from where can i have them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on your nickname in the header row of this page and the select the tab "favorites".

[image: nickname in header row]

Here all your starred questions are listed.

[image: favorites tab]

Comment: Got my answer almost completely typed out, you beat me to it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Look on [your profile page under Favorites](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1448379/alnassre?tab=favorites#tab-top).