# SO Question mysteriously converted to community wiki

Tags: support, community-wiki

[Elegant ways to support equivalence ("equality") in Python classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390250/elegant-ways-to-support-equivalence-equality-in-python-classes)

The question has not met any of [the requirements to become community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). Oddly, [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/390250/revisions) now states that the question was turned into a community wiki question immediately upon posting, yet I don't recall having posted this question as community wiki; I'm certain I gained reputation points from upvotes and accepting an answer. Why is the state of this question different now?

Comment: I'm guessing you just accidentally clicked CW, or a mod did it within 5 mins of you posting it.

Comment: @TheLQ: then the revision would say that it was gotgenes or a relevant mod who converted it.

Comment: I don't know when this happened but it might have been triggered by yesterday's activity.

Comment: If you look at your [reputation report](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation), do you see any rep-generating voting activity for that question, or is it gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm certain you accidentally marked it as Community Wiki when you first asked it. According to the [timeline of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/390250/timeline), you got upvotes as early as the day you posted it. Your [reputation graph from your profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38140?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top), however, lists no reputation gain for that question during that period. If you double-check your [reputation audit](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), I'm sure you'll find post 390250 to be equally devoid of reputation change.

As a comparison, my [answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/what-is-a-favorite-question-how-do-they-work/53580#53580) was converted to Community Wiki after it already received 4 votes. My [reputation graph](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146126?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top) also indicates the 40 reputation earned from those.

The syntax is unusual, but observing a [couple of other](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/800/revisions) [2008 Community Wikis](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/549/revisions), it seems this was how Community Wiki was performed back then.