# Pending upvotes and downvotes?

Tags: feature-request

Before you have enough reputation to vote up or down questions and answers, it would be nice if you could cast "provisional" or "pending" votes, that would only take effect when your reputation actually hit that point. They wouldn't be visible to anyone else until that point (except maybe to moderators, and distinguished as such?). That way, OCD people like me wouldn't have to worry about forgetting to upvote a really cool answer we'd seen soon after we joined the site.

This could be implemented either in the StackOverflow software itself, or as a browser plugin. (I don't think you could do it with Greasemonkey because of the persistent storage requirement, but I could be wrong.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that each question and answer has a permalink underneath for it (the link titled "link"). I think, based on Jeff's reply saying that pending votes probably won't be implemented, I'll just bookmark the ones I want to vote on but can't yet vote on, and tag those bookmarks "upvote" or "downvote".

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could just [mark the question as a favorite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/what-is-a-favorite-question-how-do-they-work), which would give you a convenient link back to the question on your profile. When you have enough Rep to vote, you can then go through your favorite list, cast your votes, then remove the question as a favorite if you no longer want to save the link.

Answer (score 1):

We are likely to do this soon-ish for edits, but I don't think we'll be doing it for votes.

Comment: Perhaps I just don't understand your plan, but this seems like a bad idea. What if someone else edits in the interim?

Comment: Sounds good to me, assuming that anyone with enough rep can approve such edits? (Or even must approve, when trying to make some other edits.)

Comment: @popular that seems unlikely, on a corpus of 1 million questions and a skadillion answers that all need editing

Comment: here's how I'm envisioning it. New user registers for the site and gets escorted to the main page. The very top question is a new question, and has some serious but easily fixed grammar problems. The new user makes the changes and provisionally saves them. I don't think it's unlikely that some other editor will make an edit before our fearless, eager new user reaches 2k rep. Perhaps the second editor will also fix some Markdown issues and/or do a retag. What happens then? (I'm going to upvote your comment just for the highly technical term "skadillion," though.)

Comment: @popular see http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8573/are-there-any-karma-based-wiki-systems/8575#8575