# how to save articles

Tags: support, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a favorite question?  How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/what-is-a-favorite-question-how-do-they-work)

Hi everyone,

I'm new to stackoverflow and am wondering is there site tool like a "Save" or "Favorite" button for each article here, you can simply click and save it for future reference? How can I save articles? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This belongs on the meta site, but I'll answer anyway.

Click on the star next to the question, you can see the favorites in your profile.