# Can I list all my votes?

Tags: support

I want to find a previous interesting post when I voted, so how can I find it quickly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't really a good way to do that as far as I know. If you downvoted the post it would've cost you reputation, so it would show up on your [reputation summary](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), but the complete list of posts you've upvoted isn't shown anywhere. In the future you can mark a question [favorite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/what-is-a-favorite-question-how-do-they-work) and it will show up [in a tab in your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/396383?tab=favorites)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the bookmark/favorite interface.  I wonder when we'll be able to browse our votes - it is definitely an important feature for me.  I can't think of any reason why the moderators would need to censor that information - after all, if we choose to revise our votes, doesn't that improve the meta moderation?

Comment: @schwabsauce I don't think it's intentionally censored, the feature just doesn't exist; there hasn't been enough of a need for them to take the time to create it