# How can I see what I voted for?

Tags: discussion, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I list all my votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71963/can-i-list-all-my-votes)

There are questions and answers I voted for that were interesting, but not favorites.  How do I get this list?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to see this info.

It was available in the past, but it was removed.