# Suggest to provide us with container-like feature to categorize our questions

Tags: feature-request

I hope my suggestion has not been suggested by others before.

I think we need a feature that behaves like a container or folder to allow us to categorize questions we post. It is very helpfull when we post many questions.

For example: I want to categorize my question into 4 groups, "satisfactorily solved", "quite satisfactorily solved", "favourite and useful questions", "miscellaneous".

---

**EDIT 1:**

Or we can create custom category tabs  for short!

Answer (score 1):

The system does have a way to mark ["favorite" posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585), but that's mainly so you get updates when they change. Categorization seems like a job for bookmarks: Make four folders in your browser with those names, and sort your SO bookmarks into them.