# Notify me of answers to other people's questions

Tags: support, notifications, bookmarks, alerts

Is there a way to have it notify me when answers or comments are posted to other people's questions?  I know how to do it for my own questions, but (unless I'm blind) I don't see where to select this.  If there is not a place to do this, please consider it a feature request.  B)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marking the question you want to follow as favorite should do the trick; you just need to click the star beneath the vote counter.

See: [What is a favorite question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/what-is-a-favorite-question-how-do-they-work)

> 2. Changes to the question will now notify users who have favorited the
>      question. Notifications include
>      comments to the question, edits, new
>      answers, and edits to answers. This is
>      a way to get updates on questions that
>      you yourself didn't ask.

Comment: to clarify, though, this only applies to the envelope icon on a specific site; the answers and replies don't show up in your global inbox

Comment: Thank you for the clarification - also good to know.

Comment: Per the link provided: "Changes to the question will eventually (but do not currently) notify users" as of 1/14/2012