# What does 'favorite question' with the star icon mean?

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a favorite question?  How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/what-is-a-favorite-question-how-do-they-work)

When would I use it? What are the consequences?

Comment: I'm not sure this was very useful to migrate here. [We already have this question covered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/what-is-a-favorite-question-how-do-they-work), and by having it on the per-site-meta, it saves users of that site a trip to a different site to figure these things out.

Comment: @Grace: This question is specifically about general SO / SE functionality, which I why I moved it. These questions don't belong on other sites. Moving and closing seemed the best option.

Comment: @Josh We address all kinds of general SO/SE functionality on per-site-metas. Part of the advantage is that it saves that community a trip to a whole different site just to figure out what a flag does. [It accounts for the majority of your Meta support tag](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support "Many of these questions are general SO/SE functionality"). Likewise, migration isn't even useful because we already have the question covered.

Comment: @Grace: Good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It marks a question as a favorite. Favorites can easily be seen under your profile.  Look in the FAQ for more details.

Not only does it make it easy to return to the question but you are also notified of edits and new answers to that question.

Comment: Well, of course I searched the faq without success for 'favorite'. And I didn't see a link to a meta/meta site, or general meta, or pure meta. It should be linked in the faq as well, imho. Where do I find it?

Comment: Here is Meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions   Sorry, I see the faq here is small.  Look at this meta question for more on favorites: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/what-is-a-favorite-question-how-do-they-work

Comment: Yes, thank you, and now that I know what I'm looking for, of course I found meta myself (links at the bottom). But if it is considered to be a part of every FAQ on stackexchange, there should be a link in every FAQ on stackexchange - else, how do you come to the idea? Do I need to read 'english', 'webmasters' and 'stats' as well?