# Bookmark questions for later view

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

I'm new to Stack Overflow.

Is there a way to bookmark and organize questions into my account, so I can review them later (I will need them later on without search)?

I have not yet gotten a minimum 15 reputation points to vote up, so I don't know yet, if questions I voted up are recorded in my account for later viewing.

Comment: You can make the questions you like the most as your favorite ones by clicking the star symbol down under the question voting. So, on your profile you have a column called favorites where you can view them again.

Comment: This question has been asked many times.. You can search those questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

- You can *favorite* a message
  (by clicking the star) to bookmark it.
- on your profile, you have a column called favorites where you can view them again.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use the favorites feature. (The little star under the vote counts). You can view all your favorites under your profile.

**ALSO**, please keep questions on stackoverflow directed towards programming and like subjects. Questions about the way the stack exchange sites work should be on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

*Edit:* Link to the FAQ for good measure. Since you're new around here it might be a good read and help you get situated.

> https://stackoverflow.com/faq

**PS** Welcome to the community.