# I like 'star'ing questions: how can I see a list of those I starred?

Tags: support, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

I've clicked the yellow star button on a bunch of questions.  How can I see them in one list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All of the questions you have starred are your favorites. You can view all of them by:

1. Clicking your username on the top of the page.

   [image: It's right next to your reputation.]
2. Clicking the favorites tab.

   [image: It's near the top of the page.]