# Need to tag the relevant question so I can visit back and answer

Tags: feature-request

I need a feature when I can tag questions just for my revisiting sake.

Case:
I am looking for getResources().getIdentifier() related problem. I see some related questions but not right answers. 
Eventually I solve my problem. Now, I want to go back to those questions and answer them.

Since I visited those pages through Google, and during my desperate search, I do not know how to get back to them and answer.

If I get something like 'tag this' or 'save to answer later' kind of link which will have all my saved questions, it will be easier for me to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know, you can [favorite questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work). There's a star under the downvote arrow. Clicking that will make the question show up in the "favorite" tab of your user profile so you can revisit it later.

You could also just temporarily set a browser bookmark, of course.