# Notifications for questions asked by others

Tags: support, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Is it possible to get inbox notifications about questions I didn't ask?  Occasionally a question pops up I'd really like to learn the answer to, when it gets one.  Occasionally it might take days until a good answer comes (for low volume tags, more academic questions with few experts, etc.)

Comment: Well, the *question* was not an exact duplicate.  I was looking for a way to get inbox notifications.  The answer here clarified that this is not possible, but favouriting provides an alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't get notifications about questions you don't ask. The closer you can get is to mark the question as favorite. If there is a change in the question, which means the question has been edited, a new answer is added, or a previous answer is edited, you will notice an asterisk in the "favorite" tab that is shown in your user profile page.

[image: screenshot]

As you see, it is not an automatic notification as you would get with questions you ask, and it doesn't help in understanding how many questions have been changed; you need to remember which questions have been changed since the last time you saw that page.

Now the user profile page is going to be changed; you can see the changes here on Meta Stack Overflow. I think the functionality will not be changed.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my comment question on the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the "star" button to add it to your favouri-wait a moment...recycling picture time.[image]

You'll get a notification when the question state changes.

Comment: Thanks, others told me this before.  But I certainly don't get an inbox notification for starred questions (I verified it for getting answers).  Is it necessary to enable this somehow?  Also, what qualifies as a change in the question's state?  Answers only or comments too?

Comment: +1 for the freehand circle!