# Is there any limit to number of question one can favorite?

Tags: support, bookmarks, rate-limiting

This may be a very strange question. But I am really interested to know if there is any limit on how many questions you can favorite here, say 50 or 100. I'm asking this question because I've favorited many questions here which are really important to me and I don't want to be in any danger of losing those favorites.

If anybody can answer my question I would appreciate it.

Comment: I have 85 favourites here on meta, so if there's a limit, it's at the very least not 50. :)

Comment: thanks..But still I'm worried if I get addicted by SO and my favorite question number crosses 500 than ? ;-)

Comment: @AnnaLear Seems like SO is my Complete reference nowadays. Even I can have a quick look at the questions bookmarked before my Job Interview.. :-))

Comment: Good question; though I don't fave many, I'd be interested in knowing. +1 about using SO as a reference. Also, I tend to use EverNote to save SO questions/answers and other material, just as a separate suggestion. www.evernote.com

Comment: @AndrewBarber : Thanks for appreciation and for site suggestion also.

Comment: @AndrewBarber :evernote is simply awesome. Really useful.Thanks a lot.

Comment: My pleasure; It's a perfect place for all tht "stuff, you might need to remember someday, and is accessible from almost any device!

Comment: @rohan-patel: I currently have 959 questions favorite-d. Now I don't know how to browse through them X_X

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. There is no limit to number of questions you can favorite. [Reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53580/187824).