# Allow me to save an answer

Tags: feature-request

I browse Stack Overflow quite frequently and I often find that when I come across a helpful answer I want to be able to save the best answer for later. It would be nice if I could save those snippets/answers to my account so later I can quickly find what I was looking for.

Comment: This is not quite what you're looking for, but may be close enough. See that star to the left of a question? You can use that to mark a question as a favorite, for later review from your profile. See [How do favorite questions work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work).

Answer (score 2):

You deliberately mention answers, however, would marking the question as a favorite work for you?

[FAQ entry on how Favorites work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Otherwise, the best option might be a note/snippet tool (such as Evernote or Springpad etc) that you use for saving information from the web which you can reference later on.

Comment: That does indeed work and I was unaware of the feature. It's not exactly what I was after, but it gets me close :) Thanks.