# How can I follow a post that I am interested in?

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Is I see a question that I am interested in, how can I be notified of answers to it?

Comment: Can we make a [FAQ for this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work) so it'll stop being asked? Oh wait...

Comment: @animuson Right, because people read the FAQ :P

Comment: @jadarnel27 If people *read* it, it would be a FRQ, not FAQ. (or maybe FRA?)

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate of how favorites work, as favorites are *one* way of tracking posts, but not the *only* way.

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of each question page, there is a link to what is known as the "question feed":

[image: question feed]

This gives you a link to an Atom feed which you can use in any compliant feed reader/application and be notified when new answers are posted to a question.

Answer (score 1):

Favorite it using the star icon underneath the vote count and you should get a notification when there are updates.