# Is the question feed of use anymore?

Tags: discussion, questions, feed

This is related somewhat to the question:

[How can I follow a post that I am interested in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119267/how-can-i-follow-a-post-that-i-am-interested-in/119270#119270)

It's currently closed as a duplicate of:

[How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

I disagree with the closure (and to some degree, the downvotes), as the question is not about *how favorites work*.

However, my interpretation of the closure and downvotes is that the community considers favorites to be the *primary* way to track questions that one is interested in over all others.

In looking back at the graphic I provided for [my own answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119270/140951):

[image]

I realize that the link to the question feed is *at the bottom of the page*, which is an indication that it has *very low priority* (whether or not it's intentional is another matter).

That said, is the question feed of use anymore, and if not, should it be removed?  Surely that computing power could be put to other good uses.

Comment: I would consider a better alternative to be adding that answer to the FAQ that exists. I don't know how many people use RSS stuff. I don't, so it's not of any use to me, personally.

Comment: @animuson I'm not sure if it should be added to the FAQ; it gets added to the FAQ, people start using it more, the question feed gets put into the links at the bottom of the question, the meta question referenced here gets reopened, **chaos ensues**.  It's a dangerous proposal at best. =)

Comment: @casperOne, that's a good question. I can only speak for myself, but I've never used that feature. For some reason, `Stack Overflow + RSS` does not work for me. Also, the people I know who are into RSS usually have truckloads of feeds to follow, so I'm not sure tracking a question this way is actually efficient in the general case. That said, are you suggesting the devs should simply cut that feature? *(Which was precognitively answered in your next comment.)*

Comment: @animuson But seriously, given how this discussion goes, it could end up with a) a feature request to remove the question feed, or b) a faq proposal or c) nothing, if the issue is decidedly neutral.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm not suggesting that they cut the feature, if that was the case, it would be tagged as `feature-request`, it's really a discussion around how the community perceives the question feed.  Based on the results, it could lead to a feature request asking for the removal, or (if people say they are important) a `faq-proposal` to update the FAQ to indicate (as per my comment to anumunsion above).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Note, I bring the power of precognition to the diamond *not* the other way around.

Comment: @casperOne, indeed, I was not saying you abused your moderator privileges to answer my question before I posted it. I trust this talent to be innate and not acquired :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It should be noted that the feed *could* have uses in applications *other* than readers.  The fact that it's Atom gives it some nice applications, I'm just not aware of them and how they're tied to SO, but generally, I imagine feed readers being the canonical example (although in that one, any *good* feed reader would allow you to aggregate feeds in some usable way).

Comment: @casperOne, very true, and I'm pretty sure the devs maintain metrics about the RSS hits and the stats involved. They might want to share that data (after, unfortunately, bearing the effort of anonymizing it).

Comment: what? we have a question feed?

Answer (score 7):

**Keep.** [Someone called it “HUGELY useful” a few months ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106199/make-it-easier-to-find-the-question-feed-icon-link).

**Keep.** This feature isn't hurting anyone, no dev has spoken up to say it's a pain to maintain or it's expensive. Why would you want to remove it?

Comment: I said negative things about it when we were discussing [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119267/how-can-i-follow-a-post-that-i-am-interested-in) in chat; I think that led to him thinking it's useless

Comment: @MichaelMeozek I think your opinion of your influence on me is... Exaggerated =).  It's just curiosity. I actually don't use *either* with any regularity.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't aware there was a question feed until I saw this question. I am likely going to add a folder in Google Reader to add these to for interesting questions.

The fact that it is a whole feed does seem to put a slight bar to its use; it's not as easy as just bookmarking a question, though the benefit is getting notification only when there are updates.

I say keep it; I think it could be very useful, to keep up to date with questions, over time.