# How do I find all my starred questions for a single Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

There's a tab for favorite questions for all Stack Overflow accounts: https://stackexchange.com/users/273436/inquilinekea?tab=favorites is an example.

But what if I just want to find my favorite questions for a single Stack Exchange site, like Academia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your profile on the individual site and click the [favorites tab](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/77/inquilinekea?tab=favorites).