# How to follow topics and questions in Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

I would like how to follow a question and its answers at Stack Overflow.

Example:
Let say I search a topic... Find a question that still has no answers, but I would like to know if and when somebody answers the question.

It would be a question that I did not ask, and also did not comment on.

Does Stack Overflow have this feature?

(I suppose that somebody asked this question, but I did not find it here.)

Comment: How can I follow question or user who similar to me? Stackoverflow can guess it by my last questions and answers and favorites.  Why don't do that for us

Answer (score 2):

Click on the Star next to the question and you will favorite it. You can then find it easily in your profile under the favorites tab.

PPS: You need to go back and accept answers to your previous questions. Click the Checkmark outline next to the answer.

Comment: Facebook like Notifications to answers/replies as well as email ones are very desirable.