# How can I be notified of new answers to a question I answered myself?

Tags: support, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Whenever I answer a question and subsequently leave the page, I only get notified of new activity when somebody comments on my answer or leaves a comment with @username in it.

I would however like to stay up-to-date on other contributions, so I can learn from them and perhaps even improve my answer.

How can I be notified of new activity on a question I've answered myself?

Comment: @TheEstablishment, the context and the root of the question is different.

Comment: I don't see how. You tagged this one [feature-request], but then answered it as if it were a support question about an existing feature. We already have one of those, I linked to it above. If anything, this question is mistagged; you're not requesting a feature, you're soliciting support on how to use an existing feature of the site to do something you want to do.

Comment: @TheEstablishment, Then I'll retag it... I am sorry... Just wanted to share the information...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to be notified of the new answers posted, you can favorite the question by clicking on the star to the left of the question.

[image: Click on the star to the left of the question]

If there are any changes like a new answer, edited answer, up/downvote, etc. You will be notified in the notification bar at the top of any StackOverflow page in a way similar to the following:

> You have 1 Favorite changes - Click here.