# Shouldn't users on stackoverflow able to SAVE their favorite questions

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Just now, and even many times before I have come across this concern that sometimes I found very excellent questions with classic answers.But then what happened it like When again I need to look into that, I can't find them.:(

I have multiple options like bookmark or save the page etc. but it also may help upto a certain level. I don't know whether its a valid request or SO already have something like this  but I think something related to this i.e saving our favorite questions should be provided.

Thanks for giving me the opportunity to give suggestions.!!
cheers..!!

Comment: nopes what is it ?

Comment: I fail to see how you ***missed*** all those duplicates...if I put that title into the box the "Questions that may already have your answer" box lights up like a christmas tree.