# How to save favorite questions

Tags: support, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Does Stack Overflow have a way of saving favorite questions that you would like to follow?

Answer (score 2):

Click the star under the upvote/downvote.  Starred questions appear on the favorites tab on your profile page.