# Where can I find the questions I have marked as favorited?

Tags: support, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Some questions are also my problems, so I marked it as  favorited, but after that, I dont know where to find those problems?

Comment: you mean Favorited question ?

Comment: see your [marked(favorited)](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1386369/andy?tab=favorites).

Comment: Or possibly questions you upvoted?

Answer (score 7):

As Jim answered, the only one-stop solution is your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1386369/andy?tab=summary).

There, look at this tab header:

> [image]

It contains various information.

- Short summary
- Answers you have given
- Questions you have asked
- tags used by you
- badges you awarded
- favorited questions
- bounties you offered
- reputation history (date-timewise)
- activity (upvote,downvote, close, suggested edit, revision etc.)

So, by looking at your profile you can have your answer for "marked" question.

Answer (score 5):

If by "marked" you mean *Favorites*, then it is in your profile.

If by "marked" you mean *accepted an answer*, then it is in your profile.

If by "marked" you mean *voted up*, then it is in your profile.