# Referencing other user's post

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

I would like to know if there is a way I can refer to others posts from my profile page. Sometimes we come across posts that we may like to refer to them later for the answers, but it seems there is no way we can add those posts in our profile page to refer to them later.

I want to know if such feature exist otherwise i would like to suggest it.

Comment: You could "favorite" the question (by clicking the little star below the voting buttons).  Then it shows on the "favorites" tab of your user profile page.

Comment: [How do favorite questions work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Comment: @jadarnel27 thanks for your reply

Comment: @Bart thanks for your reply

Comment: @EddyFreeman One tip: you don't need to thank everybody for their reply. It gets noisy after a while. We'll just assume you're grateful. ;)

Answer (score 3):

[Favorites](https://stackoverflow.com/users/983783/eddy-freeman?tab=favorites).

To add a question to your favorites tick the star icon below its score:

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: thanks for your reply