# Subscribing to a thread or marking it favorite w/out replying to it

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Is there a way to bookmark or subscribe to a thread without replying to it?  E.g. if you find a particular thread interesting and want to keep it in your favorites list.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

We don't have threads. We have Questions and Answers.

What you're asking for has been implemented as Favorites. Click the star beneath the voting buttons for what ever Question you want to follow.

If Favorites don't work for you, every question also offers an RSS feed. Just scroll to the bottom of the page and look for the link in the lower right corner. For instances, the feed for this question is https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/148174

Comment: Well... A question with a number of answers, each possibly with a number of comments might loosely be refered to as a thread, I think.