# store interesting questions in my account

Tags: support, bookmarks, posts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Is there any way to store a question someone asked in my profile ?? i got some interesting post from stackoverflow and I would like to store them in my account, not in my browser bookmarks.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Favorite the question.

Click on the star.

Comment: ups, my apologies for such stupid question......but Thanks !!