# Marking questions for late review on different device

Tags: support, questions

I am looking at a question on my tablet. I have the solution on my computer.

How do I tag or mark this question so that when I login on my computer I can directly go to this question and answer it?

Comment: Which tablet? If it runs Chrome or Firefox, set up bookmark sync.

Comment: If its chrome, there's a send to desktop option for the android client. Its a pretty elegant solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any dedicated tag like feature for this, AFAIK.

You could bookmark the page, email the URL to yourself or favorite it, and then come back to your computer and take the URL from your bookmarks, email or check your profile's favorites tab.

Comment: Does marking a question as favorite require some minimum rep?

Comment: @IcyFlame Not that I'm aware of. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585/187954) for more details on favorites.