# Notify user on response of recently up-voted question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

If user voted a question ***"recently"***, then he should be notified if any response took place on that question.

I know that making question favorite do the same but that a big choose. And many people (like me) are choosy to make someone or thing his/her favorite. But they liked the question and up-voted that.

Although It's true that it will be a real big drain in system as millions of votes took place in one time but I think it worths that, as it make people connected to those liked questions. Yes of-course you guys calculate and analyse that what **recently** should stand for in this case. And may be we can allow user to not to get the notification if they don't want.

Comment: Doesn't the hot question tab do this already?

Comment: Upvoting a question may simply means "that question has shown research effort and is a good one". It doesn't mean I have an interest of knowing what will happen to that question. Favorite a question if you want to be notified, and remove the favorite after you get the answer you wanted.

Answer (score 6):

> I know that making question favorite do the same but that a big choose.  And many people (like me) are choosy to make someone or thing his/her favorite.

I disagree. I think it's much more of an inconvenience to burden users who *don't* care with all of these needless notifications. Sure, I could ignore them, but they still pop up, I still have to look at them, and I still have to make the conscious choice to disregard them.

And the more notifications that people get and choose to ignore, the more likely they will be to ignore *all* notifications in the future. That's not something we want to start.

I think it should be a much bigger choose when deciding to implement notifications that bug the user. We should be much more choosy about making someone deal with the overhead of more notification messages.

Setting something as a favorite is not that big of a deal. The person doesn't get any reputation or anything from it. [This is exactly what favorites are designed for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work): to mark the questions that you are interested in and want to be notified about.

Were this change implemented, my voting behavior would have to change such that I *only* upvoted questions that I would otherwise favorite. That means I would never upvote questions that weren't in my top 5 or so tags, and would only rarely upvote questions to which I already knew the answer. Which sort of misses the point of voting on *good questions*.

> And may be we can allow user to not to get the notification if they don't want.

We do. We allow you to mark it as a favorite, or not mark it as a favorite. You get notified of changes to favorite questions. You don't get notified about the millions of others.

Comment: Then may be we can change **favorite** to **interested**?

Comment: What's the difference? We could change it to "pepperoni", that doesn't change how it works.

Comment: I agree, but word matters, sure you wouldn't be liked to get called something else ;)

Comment: Yeah, pepperoni would probably be a bad choice. It wasn't a serious suggestion. But what is the difference between "favorite" and "interested"/"interesting"? I'm interested in my favorite questions. And my favorite questions are interesting.

Comment: +1 for this comment as that explains. I'm little convinced.