# Following somebody else's question?

Tags: support, questions, notifications

I set a bounty on [somebody else's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13926197/redirected-forwarded-domain-with-masking-hides-remainder-of-url-after-com) for 50 rep. Will I get notified when somebody has commented or answered as if it were my own question? If not, is there a way to "follow" the question?

Comment: You'll be notified for answers posted after you posted the bounty, but not for comments. You can also favourite the question (star icon under the downvote icon), and get a few extra notifications in the [favourite questions tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2059508/jace-cotton?tab=favorites) in your profile (I don't remember what kind of notifications favouriting generates).

Comment: @Yannis Looks like a great answer - why post as a comment?

Comment: @Duncan Don't remember (and don't have time to search for) the specifics. Feel free to convert my comment to a proper answer, if you find a reference on what kind of notifications favouriting generates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YES

Whenever you set a bounty on **any** question, you'll be notified when an answer is posted but not comments. If you want to be notified of comments you have to mark the question as [favourite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Comment: That link about favourites suggests that notifications will happen *in the future*. Have they been implemented yet?

Comment: @Duncan Yes. I have experienced it