# Last visited page place holder?

Tags: support, user-interface

How can I return to my last browsed page upon returning to your site? Is there a remember my place button I'm missing?

Comment: Is that a standard feature on the sites you visit?

Comment: Perhaps it Should be...

Comment: Just a suggestion . Great site! Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

We don't have anything like that. I don't recall **any** site that will simply take you to the last page you visited when you come back to it.

However, you can favorite a question - this will put it in your favorites list on your profile page to revisit if you wish.

More details at [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

An alternative is to use the standard bookmarking facility of your browser.

Comment: or your browser history

Comment: Browser bookmarks are great but I would have to delete the old bookmark everyday before creating a new one. I just thought It would be simple enough to store a cookie of the hash and upon returning, allow me the user the option of returning to that location using the cookie data. A great place for this option would be right next to the NEXT button at the bottom of the page. "Store this location?" Like I said, great site but after a long night of browsing, would be nice to just click a single button. Thanks Oded.

Comment: @user3035019 - That may serve your needs, but how many others would that be useful to? Stack Exchange sites are Q&A sites, not online books/comic sites, where I can see such a feature being useful. Many of our users have multiple tabs open at the same time - which page should we save? The last one loaded?