# Add a page explaining the favorites feature to the Help Center

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, help-center

Currently, the Help Center [does not have any documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=favorite) regarding the Favorites feature. Considering that this is one of the most visible and a fairly useful feature of the platform, favorites should get a page on the Help Center.

Currently, [this FAQ on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585/200868) is the help page that is linked to from certain places. Instead of directing users to an MSE page from all over the Network, this FAQ should be added to the Help Center (with the necessary changes) so that it can be reached locally within a site.