# Notify when a question is answered

Tags: feature-request, answers

There are some very good questions in SE network. Some of the best questions do not have answers. I do not really have examples now. So can we bring out a feature say "Follow Question" button near the question, So clicking on the button will subscribe us to the question and when someone answers it the notification would go to those who have clicked the "Follow Question" the question.

Or is there already a feature like this ?

Comment: Also see [How do favorite questions work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Comment: By the way, to *directly receive* notifs you can just bounty the question you like. For 7 days, while the bounty is lasting, you'll receive notifs for the new answers (it is not possible for *you* cuz you have small rep, but possible for users with >75 reps, so this comment is just a note).