# How can I view vote history from all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, voting

I often use voting up a question as a way to essentially 'bookmark' a question or an answer that I can refer to later. The only issue I may run into though is that it can often be hard to tell if a question was from Security or Crypto or Stackoverflow etc--so with this, is there any central location I can view my voting history from all different exchanges simultaneously?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### To answer your question

I don't believe it's possible.

Your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/4934546/mrmayfield) has various information about your activity on all Stack Exchange sites, but not voting.

---

---

### Side topic

> I often use voting up a question as a way to essentially 'bookmark' a
> question or an answer that I can refer to later

While reasons for voting are entirely personal choice and up to us individually, can I ask you to please *consider* not voting as a way of bookmarking?

This provides false feedback for others in search results and when viewing a question or answer and expecting it to be of a certain quality based on the votes. Not expecting users to be voting to "bookmark".

---

Your voting history is not even a very useful mechanism to be using for this.

How can you easily and quickly find questions and answers of interest, if you have to trawl all your upvote history, which is not ordered in any way useful for "bookmarking"?

How do you differentiate between posts you've upvoted because of quality, and posts you've upvoted for bookmarking reasons?
Does your using voting as a mechanism for bookmarking deter you from upvoting for quality purposes so you only have votes in your history for questions you want "bookmarked"?
If so, then the site is losing valuable votes from you, and if not, it's just another reason why this is not the ideal approach.

If posts are deleted which you had upvoted (or "bookmarked") you will never know, and could spend *ages* looking through all your votes on different sites you are registered on, across months of vote history.
You will not have any confirmation "this bookmark is gone", you just will never find it.

Whereas with browser bookmarks (or another method) you would click the bookmark and be show a Stack Exchange site's page stating "not found" or "no longer exists" etc.
Then you can delete the bookmark.

### Better solutions

*Favourites:*
You could make use of the site's "favourite" questions function.

Then you have the added bonus of seeing your favourites on all sites from your network profile:
https://stackexchange.com/users/4934546/mrmayfield?tab=favorites

[How do question bookmarks work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

*Browser bookmarks:*
A better solution would be to use your browser bookmarking. Create a new folder in your bookmarks called "Stack", then sub folders in "Stack" of whatever sorts of things you bookmark.
e.g. "Interesting" or "Git" or "Nodejs" etc. Then save the questions/answers you find useful in there.

You can even have sub folders for each site of interest, and add a new folder for a site if you join a new one one.

This also allows you to bookmark an answer directly, as you can select the "share" link on the answer, paste it into your browser and click go, then bookmark that page and the browser will bookmark the page with the URL of the answer.
Loading that bookmark in the future will take you directly to the answer, as opposed to just being taken to the question and having to trawl through all answers to find and remember why you bookmarked that thread.

---

In either case, or another option, you can then vote for the right reasons (quality, useful, etc) and "bookmark" separately :)

Comment: I was in the middle of writing an answer starring favorites, but your's is much better than mine would have been. +1 for you!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I will try and use favourites in this case. Also, I don't only upvote questions to bookmark them, it just ends up being useful because I upvote questions that I usually have myself and then am able to trackback and find the answers. Thanks for a very thorough response.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not a fan of the [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263437/how-can-i-view-vote-history-from-all-stack-exchange-sites/263440#263440) here, though it's right for the OP. What if you don't know that you want to bookmark the question or answer? As you work your mind builds pointers back to what you've read or interacted with (like an MRU); looking these up is the point of history (not bookmarks). A web browser has separate functionality for looking up history and looking up bookmarks.

Using browser history is not as targeted or helpful as a site-specific history. The browser doesn't know that you interacted with a SE site by voting or performing any other activity; in e.g. Firefox you can sort history by website but I've visited many more SE Q&A pages than I've voted on.

The accepted answer doesn't go into any detail on where to look under your network profile; see the "activity" section (e.g. [User Anthony - Stack Exchange - activity](https://stackexchange.com/users/4934546/anthony?tab=activity)). This section includes histories for essentially everything but votes: accepts, posts, comments, etc. Why not votes? Under [User Anthony - Stack Exchange - bookmarks](https://stackexchange.com/users/4934546/anthony?tab=bookmarks) there is even an "added" history. Why are there voting histories per-site?

To summarize, the accepted answer is right:

> I don't believe it's possible.

It's also right with respect to the OP's original (see the question details) request to only be able to "bookmark" (he knows he wants to save a bookmark). However, to the question "How can I view vote history from all Stack Exchange sites?" the answer is that it's not possible because SE has not implemented the feature, not because you should be doing something else.

A workaround would be to comment on (or less invasively, bookmark) all questions you voted on so that these histories essentially become your voting history. These are abuses of the system, though. What if I don't want to bookmark a question long-term? What if I vote on a question once, and then again later?

Comment: I'm not sure what your own answer is adding. The accepted answer is a "No, it's not possible but here are some useful workarounds" which is legit, common, and useful. Your answer is "The other answer is wrong" with some more details I still didn't fully figure out (so not downvoting) but also can't see the added value.

Comment: I'm not saying the other answer is wrong, which is what I was trying to emphasize with "the accepted answer is right" near the end. The added value is that anyone who finds this question who was looking for an answer to "How can I view vote history from all Stack Exchange sites?" gets the more direct answer that it's not simply not possible, and a place to vote to ask for change. Let me know if I could clarify anything specifically unclear.