# Favorite questions on Stack Exchange communities I don't have account in

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

While spending time on the SE communities that I like to visit, I'll occasionally see an interesting hot network post from another community.

Now, I don't belong to that community for a reason: I'm not interesting in that subject, and I don't want to contribute to it.

However, I really like that question and I want to remember it for future reference. Sadly, I cannot star it because I am not a part of that community.

I suggest this: you can star posts from any network/community that you like. If the post is not from a community that you a part of, then the star just goes to your Stack Exchange account's starred posts page.

Comment: Why not just make a "lurker" account?

Comment: @Mat'sMug It's easier to not have to create another account.

Comment: @SirPython with the new login, you have to click one single link. That's all. Can't be easier.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I understand that.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think this can work, because starring is more than just about adding a post to your list. It's also a form of a vote (stored in the Votes table), which is shown on the site as the counter under favorite star. The author of the question may get some badge for that, too.

It makes sense that people without a profile on a given site should not be able to vote on that site's content.

Comment: Ah, I was uncertain if the star counted as a type of vote. Very valid point.

Comment: I don't doubt what you say, but if true then the [How do favorite questions work? FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53580/230506) needs updating as it states "*It's completely separate from the voting system and has no impact*"

Comment: The FAQ is meant to give a general idea of how things work, without going into technicalities. Technically, favorites are votes while votes to close are actually flags.... but this sort of thing doesn't really belong in FAQs.

Comment: Eh... if we decided this was worth doing, we would adjust the implementation. The amount of work required is certainly a roadblock, but not necessarily a reason not to do something in and of itself if we/the community is convinced that it's an important enough feature.

Answer (score 3):

> If the post is not from a community that you a part of, then the star just
>   goes to your Stack Exchange account's starred posts page.

This sounds simple in theory, but the current favourites system stores your favourites per site, and does all manner of other things like storing your total favourites on that site, badges are calculated from it, etc.

Also, what if you join a site when you already have favourites? There would have to be more code to check when a user joins a site if they have favourites for that site already and populate data in the database, etc, etc.

Plus likely other considerations.

While not the worlds hardest coding task, it's not really worthwhile for the return.

---

You could use your browser bookmarks for this. Or, just join that community and favourite the question. There are various benefits to be had for joining (such as "favourites" :D), even if it's just to favourite that question.

Might sound overkill, but it literally only takes seconds to join a new community, and with the new auto login system you don't even have to mess around logging in to them all now either.

Comment: Plus you get an association bonus and a whole additional 40 votes/day to spend!