# Serial numbers for questions

Tags: discussion, post-id

Shouldn't questions — in any community — have some handle (e.g. serial numbers) to retrieve them back the next time you visit the community?

Comment: You mean the post id?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions (and answers) already have their own ID (otherwise, it would be hard to store them in a relational database on the server). You can find it in the address bar of your browser — this question's ID is 287037.

> [image: question with address bar of browser]

Another way to get it is by clicking the 'share' link below a question or answer. The first ID in the URL is the question's/answer's ID, the second one is your user ID on that particular site.

> [image: question with share dialog opened]

And, really going [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, the best way to find questions back is to ['favourite'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work) them with the star under the vote buttons.

Comment: Glorfindel, Thanks a lot for your very clear answer

Comment: Worth to mention, this is per-site. Meaning there can be same ID on different Stack Exchange sites, giving different questions of course. /cc @VasantKumbhojkar.