# Can I separate a Stack Overflow account from other accounts on the Stack Exchange network?

Tags: support, user-accounts, linked-accounts

I was wondering whether it is possible to separate a Stack Overflow account from other accounts (e.g., for meta.SE, math.SE, etc.) such that one can use different login credentials and profiles for each of them.

I have seen that it is possible to [hide the other profiles](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/276581/165773), but I want to keep them entirely separate (or only keep some of them associated).

Comment: Yes, technically that's possible.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53580/1138813

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the profiles are already connected to the same network account, then no that is not possible. You would need to have that idea in mind when creating the profiles, and use a different email address for each site where you want to have a separate profile. Then you'd also have to make sure that you never login to those profiles with the same credentials, or do anything that got you connected as the same person, as it might result in an auto-merge.

Officially, running multiple accounts works but **is not supported** so we cannot help you in any way with separating accounts or preventing auto-merges.