# Why can I bookmark my own question?

Tags: support, bookmarks

Why can I bookmark my own question? Don't I already get a notification when something happens on my question anyway (I don't mean the actions on answers)?

Comment: I will sometimes bookmark my own questions for the sake of finding them easily. I'm almost certain that I cannot memorize [54 lines of code that do a thing I rarely need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68443887/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-slider-in-applescript)

Comment: I will remind that bookmarks are different from [following a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/follow-post/info). Following a post gives you notifications from that post, bookmarking does not. (As far as I can tell, I don't see an option to *follow* my own post.)

Comment: [How do question bookmarks work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe you've asked hundreds of questions and...

- There are a few you keep coming back to because they have useful but complicated answers and a bookmark is faster than searching each time.
- There's one you've been meaning to alter/correct but you just don't have time right now.
- There's one where you're not sure which answer is best right now so you want to remind yourself to look at them with a view to accepting and/or voting on them at a later date.

Or one of any number of reasons where you might want a reminder to revisit  one of your many questions later.