# Save or Bookmark favorite questions in Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there a way to “Bookmark” answers in stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7671/is-there-a-way-to-bookmark-answers-in-stackoverflow)
>   [Can I bookmark a question on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23670/can-i-bookmark-a-question-on-stack-overflow)
>   [Is there any way to favorite / bookmark an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1569/is-there-any-way-to-favorite-bookmark-an-answer)
>   [What is a favorite question?  How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/what-is-a-favorite-question-how-do-they-work)
>   [Is there a way I can track a particular question in stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33893/is-there-a-way-i-can-track-a-particular-question-in-stackoverflow)

Often I refer to some questions on Stack Overflow and want some way to remember them instead of going through the list and searching them via tags.

I think it would be great if a user could save or bookmark favorite questions and when these would be displayed in the user's page!

Or is there already a way to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to "Bookmark" answers in stackoverflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7671/is-there-a-way-to-bookmark-answers-in-stackoverflow) - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23670/can-i-bookmark-a-question-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 13):

Click on the star underneath the voting arrows on the question. This will add it to your favorites list, which you can then access via a tab on your profile page.

[image: Star button]
[image: Favorites]
[image: Unicorns]

Comment: Man, not even a single upvote for the freehand circles? What's wrong with meta today?

Comment: Freehand stars freehand circles are not.

Comment: The problem is that you won't see the word "favorite" unless you hover over the star. You can click on it but won't know what you did until you look on your account page. (Perhaps there should be a little notification after you click, "This question has been added to your favorites.")

Comment: @radp OK, there was a freehand star thrown in too; I figured that you had to jazz up freehand circles a little occasionally.

Comment: Fair enough, and grats on your 1k :)

Comment: Thanks a ton Brian!! Sorry for late response, was out of the world for few days.. :)

Comment: Oh gosh, so simple yet I had to read this twice it's the LITTLE STAR under the QUESTION UP & DOWN ARROWS

Answer (score 0):

Every question also has an RSS feed that you can load into your favorite reader.

For instance, this question's feed is https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/68449