# Monitoring a question without marking as favourite

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions, unanswered-questions

While looking unanswered question there are sometimes some questions which need some time to answer. Is it possible to mark this questions for monitoring without using the favourite function?

Thanks for any response.

Comment: Just keep a tab open with it?

Comment: Or place a *relevant* comment on it.  It will appear at the top of your *[recent activity](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2241653/mburm?tab=activity&sort=comments)* tab.

Comment: Good old bookmark?

Comment: Every question has an [RSS feed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/177230).

Comment: @AlEverett: That sounds like an answer.

Comment: My problems are more different locations (i.e. office and home) and major time spans. Therefore bookmarks would not help in this case. Maybe I will help me with the comments. Thanks for all hints :-)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I've made the same recommendation before. Perhaps that means this question is a duplicate.

Comment: See also: [Save or Bookmark favorite questions in Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68449)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every question has an [RSS feed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/177230). Pop the feed into your favorite newsreader<sup>1</sup> and you're good to go.

---

<sup>1</sup>Not Google Reader.